# How to add package (which is a folder on specified branch on github) to react package.json

Tags: reactjs, git, package, package.json

Let's say my repository name is: abcdef

And there is branch name: branchabcdef

On this branch there is many folders and files and one of the folders is: packages

Inside the folder: packages there is a (folder with) name of the package: mypackage

I'd like to add this package "mypackage" to react app.
Afaik this is done by adding the package to file package.json in the react application (in the dependencies tab).
but how can i do that?

```
"dependencies":{
    "mypackage": <what here>
    ...
}
```

I've seen similar questions but it turns out they weren't as much similar as i thought... thus haven't found the solution

Comment: Hi,
You can use .gitignore file to ignore the file or directory.

Comment: can you specify?

Comment: you want to install packages inside mypackage; or you want to ignore mypackage from git repository

Comment: I created locally react app and i want to add my package so i can use it in this app. Package is on github website and its name is "mypackage"

Comment: you need to build your package and publish it as npm package.
check this https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages